# What is the "runny" excretion from noses called?

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary

What is the word for the "runny" excretion from someone's nose called? from this [link](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/runny-nose-and-running-nose)

> ***Runny nose***
>   is the idiom that Americans use to describe what happens
>   when your nose **runs** (that is, when liquid comes out of your nose
>   because of a cold, allergy, or crying). This is the term for the
>   general condition of having a *running nose* and is used in a sentence
>   like the word cold when it refers to an illness.

What is this “liquid that comes out of your nose” called in English?

Comment: To clarify, you would like a single word for "a person who has a runny nose"?

Comment: Or do you want an alternative expression for "runny nose"? OR Would you like to know the name of the "runny" excretion which appears when people have bad colds?

Comment: @Mari-LouA yes i want to know the "runny" excretion which appears when people have bad colds or when they are crying

Comment: @Moudiz you mean "snot" and synonyms for it ?

Comment: @RozennKeribin snot is a slang language https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snot , I prefer something more 'formal'

Comment: @Mari-LouA yes thanks for point about it, anyhow i fixed it

Comment: The formal term is *phlegm*.

Comment: I only posted an answer because providing answers in comments is not always productive, and you had two answers in comments with no follow up. For me, *phlegm* is usually thick, sometimes coloured and something you normally cough up if you have a very bad cold.

Comment: I agree with @Mari-LouA. If it's runny, I call it "mucus."

Comment: phlegm is _not_ what comes out of your nose, snot is.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Depending on your preference:

*[snot](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/snot)* (informal), *[nasal mucus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mucus#Cold_weather_and_nasal_mucus)* (formal) or *[nasal discharge](http://www.healthline.com/health/nasal-discharge)* (medical-sounding)

The correct medical term for *runny nose* is

> **[Rhinorrhea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhinorrhea)** or **rhinorrhoea** is a condition where the nasal cavity is filled with a significant amount of mucus fluid. The condition, commonly known as a *runny nose*, occurs relatively frequently. Rhinorrhea is a common symptom of allergies (hay fever) or certain diseases, such as the common cold. It can be a side effect of crying, exposure to cold temperatures, cocaine abuse or withdrawal, such as from opioids like methadone. Treatment for rhinorrhea is not usually necessary, but there are a number of medical treatments and preventive techniques available.

Wikipedia

From *Web*MD.com

> **[Mucus](http://www.webmd.com/allergies/features/the-truth-about-mucus#1)** is something everyone has, and some people wish they had a lot less of the stringy, gooey stuff. Sure, it can be gross to blow globs of **snot** into tissue after tissue when you have a cold or sinus infection, but **mucus** actually serves a very important purpose. […] during an allergic response to an offending trigger, such as pollen or ragweed, most cells in your body squeeze out a substance called histamine, which triggers sneezing, itching, and nasal stuffiness. The tissue of the mucus membranes **starts leaking fluid, and your nose begins to run.**

Comment: Not so much "correct" as "technical."

Comment: There they are a-doin' it, just sittin' there a-chewin' it, thinkin' it's gum but it'snot.

Comment: Wow! The next time I have a cold I'm going to tell people I have rhinorrhoea to see what their reaction is!

Comment: @CJDennis: Reminds me of a lady I knew in high school who found it the height of hilarity to go to a fancy restaurant and (in a stage whisper) say something like: "Oh my god! There's a man masticating in public."

Comment: Boogers also works.

Answer (score 0):

When the liquid is thin, and non-viscous it can be called [rheum](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rheum).

> A watery fluid that collects in or drips from the nose or eyes.

Answer (score -1):

Technically speaking, the thin fluid coming from your nose due to cold weather (and not due to illness) is mostly water, which is condensed from the water-vapor rich air coming from your lungs.

Comment: so what do you call it ?

Comment: "mostly water" covers a large proportion of the liquids we encounter, making it pretty unhelpful as a description. Soup is *mostly water*, and so is eyewash, but you really don't want to get them confused.

Comment: Though interesting, this doesn't actually answer the question asked. The question is about the stuff that runs out of your nose when you *have* a cold, not when you *are* cold.

Comment: @AakashM "mostly water" in comparison to other fluids coming from the nose.

Comment: @Moudiz: No, it does not answer the question, but I thought it may be helpful for others to find better answers. I would have added it as a comment to the original question, if I could.

Comment: The human body as a whole is mostly water. Water other fluids commonly come from the nose when you have a runny nose?

Comment: If you could dismiss the non-water part so easily, humans would be akin to puddles. The fluids in your nose/throat/lungs are usually made sticky by the producing cells to catch bacteria, viruses, dust, etc, since it is a very cheap method to clean the body. In cold weather the fluid is created basically through distillation. Further reading:
http://www.webmd.com/allergies/features/the-truth-about-mucus