# what is inhaling nasal mucus called?

Tags: single-word-requests

A person with a cold will have nasal mucus in their nose building up. They continuously try to forcefully inhale the liquid mucous substance in the nose by breathing it in so that the nose stops running for a moment.

I would like to tell them not to that as over time it will cause headache. I want to know if there is a word for inhaling phlegm. For example

> Don't ________, because it will cause headache.

Comment: This is [**phlegm**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phlegm#Illnesses_related_to_phlegm), you're thinking of "runny nose" aka [nasal mucus](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/377163/what-is-the-runny-excretion-from-noses-called/377174#377174) (snot)

Comment: *expectorate* is a related antonym for the term you are looking for. It means cough or spit out phlegm from the throat or lungs.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest [*snuffle*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/snuffle) or [*sniffle*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sniffle), which have the same definition on dictionary.cambridge.org:

> to breathe in quickly and repeatedly through the nose, usually because you are crying or because you have a cold

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers. Please copy the relevant information from links into your answers here (using > to give them quote formatting). This is in case the linked website doesn't exist in the future.

Comment: And don't forget "snort".

Comment: @HotLicks I'd upvote that as an answer.

Comment: I am used to that in the OPs context being sniff - same definition in dictionary.cambridge.org (I remember this term as I am a long term Hay Fever sufferer) - snort is different

Comment: "Sniff" seems to primarily be used to describe inhaling air, but as an example of onomatopoeia this seems arbitrarily restrictive.

Comment: That said, it seems sniff/sniffle/snuffle and even inhale need to be paired with something to communicate inhalation of anything more than air.